# display hidden div attached to a option

Tags: jquery, forms

I want to display a hidden div based on a selected radio button, for example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title></title>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".option_select").click(function() {
            if ($('#extra_options').is(":hidden")) {
                $('#extra_options').slideDown("slow");
            }      
        });
    }); 
</script>        
</head>

<body>
<div id="extra_options" style="display:none;">
<input type="radio" name="ExtraOption" value="1" /> Extra option 1<br />
<input type="radio" name="ExtraOption" value="2" /> Extra option 2<br />
<input type="radio" name="ExtraOption" value="3" /> Extra option 3<br />
</div>

<form action="#" method="post">
<input type="radio" name="Option" class="option_select" value="1" /> Option 1<br />
<input type="radio" name="Option" class="option_select" value="2" /> Option 2<br />
<input type="radio" name="Option" class="option_select" value="3" /> Option 3<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

But I'd really like to attach that #extra_options div to the selected radio button ("Option 1, Option 2, Option 3 etc),  so it looks more like "these extra options go with this option #". I figured I could have a #extra_optionsX div attached to every single radio button but I figured there was a better way then that. Any ideas?

TIA

Comment: suggest you create the markup and css the way you want it to look and create live demo in jsfiddle.net. You can clone the `extra_options` as many times as you want and make them instance independent. All depends on what behavior you are looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can append it using

```
if ($('#extra_options').is(":visible")) {
    $('#extra_options').hide();
}
$(this).next().after($('#extra_options'));
$('#extra_options').slideDown("slow");
```

(edit: added hiding/showing when changing selected options)

Comment: Thanks, this worked great. For some reason if I do $(this).next().after($('#extra_options')); within the success function of a ajax call then it doesn't work (it stays on top of all the options), but If I set it before the ajax then it does work. Strange but at least it works, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A working code is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/stefanz/L44Hb/) .

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form > input').click(function(){
        var t = $(this),
            extra = $('#extra_options');

        $('input[value=' + t.val() + ']', extra)
            .parent()
            .show()
            .siblings()
            .hide();

    });
});​
```

Better to wrap all inputs with text in a `<label>`, something like : `<label><input type="radio" name="foo" value="bar" /> Its value here </label>`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll add the label tags. I wanted to give this a try but it didn't work like I wanted, it kept displaying the extra option at the top, above all the other options instead of below the section option (in jsfiddle.net too)